# Read Json and put inside a model.(Code Igniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to read a json file and load into Code Igniter's MVC format and how can i send json data to the view file and show it there.

Detail example

```
   {
    "itemName"          : "Giordana",  
    "itemId"            : 450,
    "itemPrice"         :45,
    "itemCategory"      : "Shirit" ,
   }
```

Please help me with details step-by-step if possible.

```
   1. Route
   2. controller
   3. Model
   4. View
```

I swear, I will do the whole project by myself but I just need a head start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the JSON data decode that using `json_decode($encoded_json_data_string)`

To get JSON data from a url you can use curl library to call an url. You need to send parameters which you like to pass to your model function through the url. So create a file in that call your model function and to that function pass the parameters which you passed in the url here.

```
 In the file
 $result = $this->model->function_name(arguments);
 echo json_encode($result);
```

In the controller function you need to extract that like below.

```
$data = $this->curl->simple_get($url_path);
```

For Example

```
$data = { "itemName" : "Giordana",
"itemId" : 450, "itemPrice" :45, "itemCategory" : "Shirit" , };

$result = json_decode($data,true);
```

You need to do above two steps in the controller function and then if you want to show that json data in the view file You just need to pass that array $result to view.

```
$this->load->view('view_file',$data);
```